# matplotlib subplots arrangement

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have some issues with adjusting the spacings between subplots. Although there are a lot of questions regarding similar issues I couldn't find a suitable solution.

Here is a simple example with a plot of random values and two images with colorbars in one figure:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 8), nrows=3, ncols=1)

ax1.plot(np.random.rand(100))
ax1.set_ylabel('y-label')
ax1.set_xlabel('x-label')

im2 = ax2.imshow(np.random.random(size=(50, 100)))
ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
divider2 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax2 = divider2.append_axes("right", "5%", pad="3%")
cbar2 = plt.colorbar(im2, cax=cax2, orientation='vertical')

im3 = ax3.imshow(np.random.random(size=(50, 100)))
ax3.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax3.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
divider3 = make_axes_locatable(ax3)
cax3 = divider3.append_axes("right", "5%", pad="3%")
cbar3 = plt.colorbar(im3, cax=cax3, orientation='vertical')

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

How can I:

- reduce the spacing between the two lower images, similar to the distance between the plot and the first image?
- shift both images to the left, such that they are aligned with the y-label of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a gridspec layout to place your subplots in. The tricky bit is then to get the parameters right. This would require a little bit of testing.

Here the idea is to create a gridspec with 4 rows and 2 columns. The lower two subplots would span both columns, while the upper subplot only the last. There would also be an empty row to account for the extra space needed for the upper plot's x label.

[image]

Of course you should then not call `tight_layout` as that would scramble all the nicely set parameters again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 8))

gs = GridSpec(nrows=4, ncols=2,height_ratios=[1.2, .1, .8, .8],
                               width_ratios=[.1, 1], 
                               hspace=0.05, wspace=0.1,
                               left=0.05, right=0.9, 
                               bottom=0.02, top=0.98)

ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[2,:])
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[3,:])

ax1.plot(np.random.rand(100))
ax1.set_ylabel('y-label')
ax1.set_xlabel('x-label')

im2 = ax2.imshow(np.random.random(size=(50, 100)))
ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
divider2 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax2 = divider2.append_axes("right", "5%", pad="3%")
cbar2 = plt.colorbar(im2, cax=cax2, orientation='vertical')

im3 = ax3.imshow(np.random.random(size=(50, 100)))
ax3.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax3.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
divider3 = make_axes_locatable(ax3)
cax3 = divider3.append_axes("right", "5%", pad="3%")
cbar3 = plt.colorbar(im3, cax=cax3, orientation='vertical')


plt.show()
```

[image]